# Return on result set from many tables using a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I just  practice with cursor. I want to Merage all table together. I hope you can understand my purpose.
Can I return all result into 1 temporary table

```sql
DECLARE @dep NVARCHAR(max) = 'Computer Studies,Civil Engineering'
declare @tmpTable table (
    Table_Name NVARCHAR(max)
    ,Count int
)
declare cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT * FROM dbo.DEPARTMENTS  
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.DEPARTMENTS WHERE DepartmentName = @dep
    fetch next from cur
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)a

Comment: *" I hope you can understand my purpose."* Not really; you don't ask anything, and normally a `CURSOR` is the wrong choice when writing SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a temporary table to accumulate the results, eg

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @dep NVARCHAR(max) = 'Computer Studies,Civil Engineering'
declare @tmpTable table (
    Table_Name NVARCHAR(max)
    ,Count int
)
declare cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT * FROM dbo.DEPARTMENTS  

drop table if exists #results 
select * into #results from dbo.DEPARTMENTS where 1=0
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #results
    SELECT * FROM dbo.DEPARTMENTS WHERE DepartmentName = @dep
    fetch next from cur
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

select * from #results
```

Comment: This begs the question of why use a `CURSOR` at all; it'll be terribly slow.

Comment: OP: "I am just practicing with cursors"

Comment: That doesn't change my point; even for practice this is doesn't really make sense as a method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a cursor here. Don't practice with it, it's a waste of time. They are slow, inefficient, and nearly always unnecessary.

Instead use set-based logic, by placing your conditions in a table variable or Table Valued Parameter

```sql
DECLARE @deps TABLE (dep nvarchar(100) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @deps (dep)
VALUES ('Computer Studies'), ('Civil Engineering');

SELECT *
FROM dbo.DEPARTMENTS d
WHERE d.DepartmentName IN (
    SELECT t.dep
    FROM @deps t
);
```

Comment: thank you for ur advice but I want just one condition with differnce value

Comment: So why not just a simple `SELECT ... WHERE DepartmentName = @dep` why the cursor?

Comment: I have 3 records in table A and  table B related to table A, so I want to use the record in table A to ask the Condition value for each record from table A, So I use Cursor and fetch next to loop for each record.

Comment: I don't see two tables in your question, but it still sounds like you just need a join or an `IN` or `EXISTS`